# How to move a file from one directory to another in NSFilesystem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

As we move a xml file  from our project,i.e using the code 
`[self MoveFilesToMyDocFolder:@"Config.xml"];` and by the method

```
- (void)MoveFilesToMyDocFolder:(NSString *)destfileName
```

similarly how can we move a xml file from one directory to another directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 
`moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:`  or `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:`

Pl. refer this [page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @sujay: `moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:` and `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` can be used to move and copy both files and folders (hence `item` appearing in the method name).

Comment: Is this the answer required by you?